# Spring Rest Json Mapping on POST (Invalid Property)

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

This is a weird one for me. I've done the entities and the controllers and the form validation before, but I'm confused on this error.

So backstory. This is spring-boot w/Hibernate, connecting to a PostgreSQL Db. What I am attempting to do, is map a POST request to creating a resource. I'm trying to do this with pure JSON. I've been able to achieve this before.

The error in question is...

> Invalid property 'Test' of bean class [com.example.api.entities.forms.OrganizationRegistrationForm]: Bean property 'Test' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The request body, as it is in Postman is...

```
{
   "organizationName":"Test",
   "employees":10
}
```

The **OrganizationRegistrationForm** class it's complaining about...

```
public class OrganizationRegistrationForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String organizationName = "";

    @NotNull
    private int employees;

    private JsonNode contactInfo;
    private JsonNode locationInfo;


    public String getOrganizationName() {
        return organizationName;
    }
    public void setOrganizationName(String name) {
        this.organizationName = name;
    }
    public int getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
    public void setEmployees(int employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
    public JsonNode getContactInfo() {
        return contactInfo;
    }
    public void setContactInfo(JsonNode contactInfo) {
        this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    }
    public JsonNode getLocationInfo() {
        return locationInfo;
    }
    public void setLocationInfo(JsonNode locationInfo) {
        this.locationInfo = locationInfo;
    }


}
```

And in case you need it, the request method...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/organization", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Organization registerOrganization(@Valid @RequestBody OrganizationRegistrationForm form,
            BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            LOGGER.error("The registration form entered has errors: {}", bindingResult.getAllErrors().toString());
            throw new InvalidForm();
        }

        try {
            Organization org = orgService.registerOrganization(form);
            if(org!=null)
                return org;
        } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            bindingResult.reject("name.exists", "The supplied name is already in use");
        }

        throw new InvalidForm();
    }
```

Although I'm guessing it doesn't even get that far. Originally the orginazationName field was called "name", but I changed it to see if maybe that was the issue.

The even weirder part for me is when I used this JSON object it worked. But created an organization named "organizationName".

```
{
    "organizationName":"organizationName",
    "employees":10
}
```

And one time it even complained that the invalid property was ''. As in empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure Spring attempts to parse your body as a JSON? Add ` consumes="application/json"` to `@RequestMapping` (and see if request fails) or check your request headers...

Comment: @JanChimiak see my strange answer to this strange problem. And my headers where Content-Type: "application/json" anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, or why. But for some reason the answer seemed to be in the **OrganizationRegistrationFormValidator** class that the binder uses.

The evil line in question was in *validate(Object target, Errors errors)* method...

```
 ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, target.getOrganizationName(), "name.empty", "Please enter a name");
```

Changing that line to a classic check worked.

```
if(target.getOrganizationName.isEmpty())
   errors.reject("name.empty", "Please enter a name");
```

For documentation sake, anyone know why that happened? Are my api docs wrong when IntelliSense suggested that method signature?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I just stumbled over it:

to me `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, target.getOrganizationName(), "name.empty", "Please enter a name");` looks wrong.

It should be:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "organizationName", "name.empty", "Please enter a name");
```

The second attribute is the Field Name, not its content. ValidationUtils will take that name and transform it to the standard getter (getOrganizationName in that case) to retrieve its value and validate that.

This is why it tells you ther is no property named Test. Because there is none.